# gcc is unable to create an executable file when installing FFmpeg

Tags: gcc, ffmpeg

I'm trying to install FFmpeg directly from the source and I keep getting this error:

```
gcc is unable to create an executable file.
If gcc is a cross-compiler, use the --enable-cross-compile option.
Only do this if you know what cross compiling means.
C compiler test failed.

If you think configure made a mistake, make sure you are using the latest
version from Git.  If the latest version fails, report the problem to the
ffmpeg-user@ffmpeg.org mailing list or IRC #ffmpeg on irc.freenode.net.
Include the log file "config.log" produced by configure as this will help
solving the problem.
```

Can anyone help? Also, yum install ffmpeg doesn't work.

Comment: The tail of `config.log` would be useful.

Comment: ./configure: line 640: gcc: command not found
C compiler test failed.    Is that something?

Answer (score 3):

Apparently, with the limited information I have, you need to at least install `gcc` to compile ffmpeg. See [How to Compile FFmpeg on CentOS](https://ffmpeg.org/trac/ffmpeg/wiki/CentosCompilationGuide) for instructions. It is designed for CentOS, but should work for RHEL and Fedora.

Alternatively you can simply use a [static build of ffmpeg](http://ffmpeg.org/download.html#LinuxBuilds) instead of compiling, but it doesn't have the advantage of customization that compiling provides.

Note that Stack Overflow is limited to programming questions and discussions.